# Make an NSString accessible in the whole class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I want to know how can I make an NSString accessible in the whole class. Say I have these codes:

```
    - (void) init { 
        NSArray *elements  = [xpathParser search:@"//foo"];
            TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *data  = [element content];

        NSArray *elements1  = [xpathParser search:@"//foo2"];
            TFHppleElement *element2 = [elements1 objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *data2 = [element2 content];
    }
```

And I want to use data & data2 in the whole class, how can I do that?

I want to show results here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell.


    switch (indexPath.row) {

        case 0 :

            cell.textLabel.text = (@"%@", data);

            break;

        case 1: 

            cell.textLabel.text = (@"%@", data2);

            break;
}
    // Email & Password Section


    return cell;    
}
```

Comment: Do you want them just available inside that instance of the class, or all instances?

Comment: `            cell.textLabel.text = (@"%@", data2);` is nonsense.

Comment: so you want it to be `static`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make them variables inside the class by declaring them outside of the method, like:

```
NSString *data;
NSString *data2;

- (void) init { 
  NSArray *elements  = [xpathParser search:@"//foo"];
  TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
  data = [[element content] retain];

  NSArray *elements1  = [xpathParser search:@"//foo2"];
  TFHppleElement *element2 = [elements1 objectAtIndex:0];
  data2 = [[element2 content] retain];
}
```

and later:

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [data release];
  [data2 release];
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to access the results from? If you update your question to illustrate your point, it will make it possible to give you a better answer.

Comment: I've updated my question, thank you so much for looking at it. :)

Comment: You'll want to call `retain` on it, I believe. Like `data2 = [[element content] retain];`

Comment: The reason it was coming blank was that the tableView was getting loaded before the login process and it was not able to get the data via cookies. So what I'm actually doing now is, I'm reloading the tableView as soon as the login procedure gets completed so it can read the cookies and get the actual data. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @OhhMee - set this up as a property then, and just memoize the values.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make them `properties` and use the generated setters?

So in your `.h` file:

```
@interface YourClass  {
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *data;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *data2;
```

In your `.m` file:

```
@synthesize data, data2;
- (void) init { 
    NSArray *elements  = [xpathParser search:@"//foo"];
        TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
        [self setData:[element content]];

    NSArray *elements1  = [xpathParser search:@"//foo2"];
        TFHppleElement *element2 = [elements1 objectAtIndex:0];
        [self setData2:[element2 content]];
}
```

Comment: Nope, it's still coming as blank data. :(